# Performance: Ajax+eval vs. iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, eval

I need to load in my current page a html fragment of a remote, dynamic page (same domain), and I am trying to understand the performance impact of using a simple (hidden) iframe vs. using ajax+eval (or $.load in jQuery).

It seems to me that both are basically doing the same, as in both cases the html needs to be loaded and the scripts evaluated. So the result looks the same to me.

Am I missing something, and could somebody explain how the additional effort of using ajax+eval brings performance improvements?

I insist that the remote page I am dealing with is dynamic, and the scripts need to be evaluated. It is different from a simple GET to retrieve static content.

Comment: The fact that the content is dynamic shouldn't make a difference. Performance-wise, you shouldn't be worrying about performance because the speed of getting the data is dwarfed by the time it's going to take to make the request. The deciding factor should be which one is less error prone and easier to maintain.

Comment: @zerkms To run the scripts from the remote page, as they modify the page html. Just like jQuery does in the $.load function.

Comment: @KevinB thx for the comment. Personally I find iframes pretty straightforward - no risk, no maintenance headache, especially compared with the effort of processing an ajax response.